# Python: printing characters - nested loop or joining a string?

Tags: python, arrays, string

Let's assume I have a list:

```
cities = ['Berlin','London','Chicago']
```

And I would like to print each letter in that list individually.

Is either one of these ways more efficient or recommended?

This:

```
for c in cities:
    for l in c:
        print l
```

or this:

```
for l in ''.join(cities):
    print l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is "more efficient", without context.

The nested loops will work on any list of cities, however large, provided you have managed to construct it in the first place. It has the extra overhead of running an outer loop that repeatedly re-initializes the inner loop.

The second one avoids that, but has to construct a second copy of all the data `''.join(cities)` to iterate through. If your list of cities is large enough or your environment short enough on memory, it will fail where the first one would succeed. Also it generates more garbage that will need reclamation.

Almost certainly either will get the job done fast enough, unless you are developing for  a pea-brained embedded system with very limited RAM. In general on modern PC systems with GHz CPUs and Gbytes of RAM, efficiency should not be your first consideration. One exception is where you can predict that the amount of data you need to assemble in RAM is in danger of exceeding the amount of available RAM, in which case avoiding full intermediate copies is worthwhile. The other is where you have algorithms of different order and cannot *absolutely* guarantee that the amount of data will always stay small. In that case prefer an algorithm of lower order. O(N) trumps O(N^2) to a huge extent when N gets large!

Answer (score 4):

"what would be more efficient" often depends on OS and other factors. However, you could do a really simple benchmark:

```
cities = ['Berlin','London','Chicago']
import time

start = time.time()
for x in range(100000):
    for c in cities:
        for l in c:
            pass
end = time.time()
print "method 1: " + str(end-start)

start = time.time()         
for x in range(100000):     
    for l in ''.join(cities):
        pass
end = time.time()
print "method 1: " + str(end-start)
```

On windows 8 with python 2.7 I got:

```
method 1: 0.218999862671
method 1: 0.141000032425
```

I believe most systems will have similar results.

Anyway, sound to me like you are getting into useless premature optimizations. Are you sure you really need that level of efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a third option that you should test (the speed will depend on your use case):

```
print '\n'.join(''.join(cities))
```

because each call to print has quite a bit of overhead so it's often good to use as few as possible (one in this case).

Answer (score 0):

@ronen-ness already has [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36715560/1335793) for this pointing out that worrying about it is a premature micro-optimization.

I want to add that when trying to time code with Python the best option is to use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) rather than write your own basic test.

Re-writing that looks like:

```py
import timeit

method1 = '''
for c in cities:
    for l in c:
        pass
'''

method2 = '''
for l in ''.join(cities):
    pass
'''
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=method1, setup="cities = ['Berlin','London','Chicago']", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=method2, setup="cities = ['Berlin','London','Chicago']", number=100000))
```

```
0.046141645999999994
0.04605432300000001
```

When I run the original the results are like

```
method 1: 0.09271407127380371
method 2: 0.09324479103088379
```

The timing results are a lot faster as timeit uses the correct clock for Mac / Win / Linux, it switches off garbage collection and removes a bunch of other overhead from the measurement.

However - In both the timeit and the original, the numbers are ^wildly varying. In the runs I did, sometimes the first method was faster and sometimes it was the second. That tells me they are effectively the same; there is no statistically significant difference. The variations will be due to other things happening on the machine.

*^relatively speaking, because a millisecond difference for 100K iterations means nanoseconds per iteration which is just not worth your time. I have spent many billions of nanoseconds just writing this.*